# Why do I get the an out of memory error when I use using?

Tags: c#, using, memorystream

I have the following method, to convert a `BitmapImage` to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`:

```
public static Bitmap BitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        encoder.Save(ms);

        bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Whenever I try and use the returned Bitmap object, I get the following error:

> OutOfMemoryException occured - Out of memory.

However, whenever I replace the code with this:

```
public static Bitmap BitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));

    encoder.Save(ms);

    return new Bitmap(ms);
}
```

This works fine. However, I am pretty sure that I am supposed to use **using** as the `MemoryStream` object implements `IDisposable`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bitmap's constructor [Bitmap Constructor (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) claims that

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap.

In your case, when you're using `using` statement, stream (being Disposable) automatically disposed, so your Bitmap object becomes invalid. It's not about that you allocate too much memory, but about that bitmap point to -something that no longer exists.

Comment: What's the recommended workaround? Creating a temp bitmap, copying it (with `new Bitmap(temp)` or `temp.Clone()`) and then disposing the temp?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: it **should** be possible (not really sure on this) to avoid maintaining stream alive, if you clone bitmap into another instance and only after destroy a stream.

Answer (score 1):

What **@Tigran** said was absolutely correct, and I implemented **@CodesInChaos**' workaround like so:

```
public static Bitmap BitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        encoder.Save(ms);

        using (var localBitmap = new Bitmap(ms))
        {
            bitmap = localBitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, localBitmap.Width, localBitmap.Height),
                   PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);  
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: don't forget to dispose `localBitmap`

Comment: The jpeg part is weird. Why would you save as jpeg and then load it again? only effect of that is reducing the quality. Use a lossless format, such as `.bmp` as serialization format.

Comment: I'm working in WPF, and I need to use Aforge, so I think I need to convert to a Bitmap object, do what I need to do with Aforge, and then convert back, should I not do that? Also I actually am working with a BMP file, but I have found that the JpegBitmapEncoder works too, as do a few of the other encoders, and some are faster than others so I am trying out each one to see which gives me the best performance

Comment: My problem isn't with that conversion(though there are better ways), but mainly with your choice of JPEG over a lossless format(.bmp).

Comment: When I was testing, I found the JpegBitmapEncoder to be the fastest encoder that worked, but I didn't realise it would result in quality loss versus the slower BitmapEncoder, is that what you are getting at?

Comment: Surprising that bitmap encoding would be slower. Bitmap encoding shouldn't be much more than a memcopy. And yes, I'd worry about the quality loss due to the jpeg encoding.